# How can I present an Alert programmatically Swift 5, SwiftUI in 2022

Tags: swiftui, alert, swift5

I'm looking to show an Alert without needing to press a button, i.e. programmatically. In Swift 5 / SwiftUI in 2022.

Searching has shown me this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "alert", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When trying the above code it has issue with the nil in the completion block, but when changing it to curlys it says the view file doesn't have `present`. Looks to not be for SwiftUI.

How can I show an Alert in Swift 5/SwiftUI without needing a button press?

Comment: In SwiftUI, you can have a dedicated view model, with a published var that triggers the .alert() modifiers in the views. The problem is when you have other modal views already open: SwiftUI has issues dismissing overlapping modal views.

Answer (score -1):

Following this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591742/2066855) I was able to get the following code working

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // pass this var as binding to other views
    @State var showAlert = false
    
    func notificationReminder() -> Alert {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Notifications Required"),
                message: Text("Please authorize notifications by going to Settings > Notifications > Remindr"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("this is my main view")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert,
               content: { self.notificationReminder() })
        
    }
    
}
```

using code I then flipped showAlert