# SwiftUI 2 pop to root view with no Scene delegate

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to refresh root view when user logs out but I can’t find how to do it under the new Scene-less SwiftUi 2.

Next is [@Swissmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461933/swiftui-how-to-change-rootview-controller-programmatically) posted solution I'm trying to implement in SwiftUI 2:

```
let contentView = AppRootView(showingView: ShowingView(showingView: appStartView))

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A possible solution is to create an `ObservableObject` that is responsible for *routing*:

```
enum AppView {
    case login, main
}

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    // here you can decide which view to show at launch
    @Published var currentView: AppView = .login
}
```

Then, you can inject this `ViewRouter` as an `EnvironmentObject` to the root view:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environmentObject(viewRouter)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can change the *current view* from any view:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentView == .login {
                LoginView()
            } else if viewRouter.currentView == .main {
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Login View")
            Button("Log in") {
                viewRouter.currentView = .main
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Main View")
            Button("Log out") {
                viewRouter.currentView = .login
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not relible, I use it on my app
a lot of time token does expire, or user did tap on logout, it won't return to login page !
few time it worked !